# Does a formal specification exist for the Groovy programming language?

Tags: groovy

The title says it all. To add Groovy support to projects like doxygen or to develop IDE plugins it would VERY helpful to have a formal specification of the Groovy programming language. I did not find one on the internet.

Can anyone tell me if such spec exists and how it could be obtained? If it does not exist, does anyone know if people are working on one?

Comment: I must not understand what you mean by formal exactly. There is a [language specification](http://www.groovy-lang.org/documentation.html#languagespecification) on their site.

Comment: And the antlr script for parsing groovy [is here](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g)

Comment: Mike, my understanding would be identical with the common understanding of »formal specification« in computer science.
Tim, thank you. I think that will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User tim_yates pointed out in the comment to my question that there is an antlr script available at:
https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/antlr/groovy.g

I accept that as an answer.